# Gas burner turns on and off

Tags: gas

When I switch on my gas burner it comes on for a few minutes then the pilot light will go out. After a few minutes the pilot light comes back on and it keeps repeating this. The radiators are getting warm but nowhere near as hot as the should be.

Comment: Pilot light or burner?

Comment: The pilot light goes on and off every couple of minutes

Comment: Could you provide the model and name

Comment: All I can see is Glowworm Compact, I cannot see a model

Comment: It is the same front as this one https://www.diynot.com/diy/media/untitled.40812/full

Comment: Since I don't know that brand I could only guess that there is a flame sensor that is failing turning off the gas and restarting but without a model # this is a total guess. Look up glow worm flame sensor there are several different ones but my guess the sensor is dirty or dying